# What is the proper way of using a source generator in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, code-generation

In my C++ project I'm using a source generator to embed some resources into the binary.

I use CMake to build my project and my code works but had some issues.
I am pretty sure that what I want to accomplish is possible but I didn't find any answer online.

The current problems I have are:

- The generator runs every time, even if the input files did not change.
  This is not too big of a deal because it is really fast, but I hopped there was a better way to do it
- While using `Ninja` the generator runs at every build (as described above) without rebuilding every time.
  I think that Ninja sees that the file has not changed and does not build it again,
  but when I make changes in the resources change it still uses the old version.
  It takes another build to "realize" that the generated file has changed and rebuild it
- While using `Make` the code rebuilds every time, even when the generated file does not change, resulting in wasted build time

In both cases (looking at the output) the generator runs before the compiler.

This situation is not unsustainable but I was wondering if a better solution was possible.
Here's a code snippet from my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_subdirectory(Generator)
file(GLOB RESOURCES Resources/*)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT src/Resources/Generated.hpp src/Resources/Generated.cpp
    COMMAND Generator ${RESOURCES}
    DEPENDS ${RESOURCES}
    DEPENDS Generator
)

add_custom_target(Generated DEPENDS src/Resources/Generated.hpp src/Resources/Generated.cpp)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} Generated)
```

[Here's a minimal reproducible example](https://github.com/billy4479/generator-example), sorry for not having it before.

---

EDIT: I implemented the functional solution from the correct answer in the `fix` branch, on the same repo. It might be useful for future reference :)

Comment: If you've got a file that is generated properly (as described in the answer), you don't actually need a separate target+add a dependency, unless you want to make it possible to generate only the files: simply list both generated files (absolute paths) in the list of sources for `${PROJECT_NAME}` and cmake should realize those files may need updating.

Comment: Furthermore the use of `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` should be avoided: It relies on the presence of the `project` command in a specific cmake file putting restrictions on other parts of the file you must be aware of when modifying the file. Use `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` which always refers to the dir containing the `CMakeLists.txt` file containing the variable reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is interesting, because there are *multiple* errors and stylistic issues, which partially overlap each other.

First off:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC src/*.cpp src/*.hpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC})
```

While convenient in the beginning, globbing your sources is not a good idea. At some point you will have a `testme.cpp` in there that should not be built with the rest, or a `conditionally_compiled.cpp` that should only be compiled if a certain option is set. You end up compiling sources that you really did not intended to.

In this case, the file `src/Generated.hpp` from your git repository. That file is supposed to be *generated*, not checked out from repo. How did it even get in there?

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT src/Generated.hpp
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/generator.sh
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Resources/data.txt
            > ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Generated.hpp
    DEPENDS Resources/data.txt
    DEPENDS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/generator.sh
)
```

Do you see the output redirection there? You wrote to `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`. That is not a good idea. Your source tree should never have anything compiled or generated in it. Because these things end up being committed with the rest... like it happened to you.

Next issue:

```
add_custom_target(Generated DEPENDS src/Generated.hpp)
```

This creates a `make` target `Generated`. Try it: `make Generated`. You keep getting the following output:

```
[100%] Generating src/Generated.hpp
[100%] Built target Generated
```

Obviously it does not realize that `Generated.hpp` is already up-to-date. Why not?

Let's look at your custom command again:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT src/Generated.hpp
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/generator.sh
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Resources/data.txt
            > ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Generated.hpp
    DEPENDS Resources/data.txt
    DEPENDS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/generator.sh
)
```

What if I told you that your `OUTPUT` is never actually generated?

Quoting from [CMake docs on `add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html?highlight=add_custom_command), emphasis mine:

> OUTPUT
>
> Specify the output files the command is expected to produce. If an output name is a relative path it **will be interpreted relative to the build tree directory** corresponding to the current source directory.

So your output claims to be to the **binary** tree, but your command's redirection is to the **source** tree... no wonder the generator keeps getting re-run.

Having your header generated in the wrong location does not give you a *compiler* error, because that header from your **source** tree gets picked up by your `GLOB_RECURSE`. As that one keeps getting re-generated, your executable keeps getting recompiled as well.

Try this from your build directory:

```
mkdir src && touch src/Generated.hpp && make Generated
```

Output:

```
[100%] Built target Generated
```

You see that `make` has nothing to do for the `Generated` target, because it now sees an `OUTPUT` of your custom command that is newer than its dependencies. Of course, that `touch`ed file isn't the generated one; we need to bring it all together.

---

**Solution**

Don't write to your source tree.

Since `${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src` does not exist, you need to either create it, or live with the created files on the top dir. I did the latter for simplicity here. I also removed unnecessary `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` uses.

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT Generated.hpp
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/generator.sh \
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Resources/data.txt \
            > Generated.hpp
    DEPENDS Resources/data.txt
    DEPENDS generator.sh
)
```

Don't glob, keep control over what actually gets compiled:

```
add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp )
```

Add the binary tree to your target's include path. After `add_executable`:

```
target_include_directories( ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} )
```

That's it, things work as expected now.

Comment: I added an example, sorry for not having it before

Comment: @Billy: See updated answer.

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow, but thank you so much for your time.

Comment: It did fix my problem! I'm still a newbie (in case you didn't notice...), your help means a lot, thank you :)